# Why @F is not set by default?

Tags: perl

When `-n` or `-p` is set, to get a field by number, one has to also pass `-a` option to use `@F`.

Why all the built-in variables are set except @F has to be manually set? Especially when -n is on? It makes more sense to me to just set by default. Is there a specific reason?

Comment: Because the number of programs that don't need to recreationally waste CPU cycles splitting *every* line of input are legion?

Comment: Presumably because splitting each line takes work. If you're trying to process millions of lines, that's a lot of wasted time. If they're long lines, that's a lot of wasted time and memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Why all the built-in variables are set except @F has to be manually set?*

How can a variable have a value before it's set?

A lot of variables reflect system calls (e.g. `%ENV` reflects `getenv`) or internal Perl variables (`$!` reflects `errno`). Accessing these variables access the reflected variable or system call — they don't actually have a value of their own, so they appear to have a value at all times.

But `@F` doesn't reflect anything. In fact, it's not a special variable at all. Like `$_`, `@ISA`, etc, etc, etc, it doesn't have a value until you give it one.

Now, `readline` could be changed to populate `@F` when it reads a line from a file, but what an incredible waste of resources that would be!!! You're suggesting that Perl should create a string for every word of every file just to avoid specifying one letter to activate an incredibly rarely used feature. That's oh so wrong.

Answer (score 2):

:)Because it isn't?

Also, @F isn't exactly a  built-in variable, its created by -a

```
$ perl -we " print @F "
Name "main::F" used only once: possible typo at -e line 1.

$ perl -wae" print @F "

$ perl -MO=Deparse -ne print
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    print $_;
}
-e syntax OK

$ perl -MO=Deparse -ane print
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    our(@F) = split(' ', $_, 0);
    print $_;
}
-e syntax OK
```